# Raspberry Pi UART Pins as General Purpose

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi, iot, uart, windows-10-iot-core

I am using Raspberry Pi Model 3B with Windows IoT Core. I want to use 8 and 10 no. pins(GPIO-14 & GPIO-15) general purpose but when I tried to open pins an exception thrown that is

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Element not found.

Pin ' is not available. It is reserved by the system or in use for another function.'

How can I use these pins as GPIO on Windows IoT Core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the exception message informs, the UART pins are reserved by the system so you can't use it as other purpose. All GPIO pins are accessible through APIs listed in this picture:

[image]

Ref: [Raspberry Pi 2 & 3 Pin Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/pinmappings/pinmappingsrpi)

You can use other pins in above picture as general purpose instead of UART pins.